Accidental ETH Base Exodus to ETH Kraken
Just need an answer wether i should have some hopes or not. Accidentally sent £500 BASEETH TO ETH Wallet and has succesfully confirmed on blockchain! No coins appeared and Kraken is simply saying your money can be recovered but we are not interested in doing so as it will cost us money. Kinda let down for someone who uses them on regular occasion and probably made 10x in fees of me! But yet when customer makes mistakes they not willing to help at all! Exodus people are on other hand still sends emails that they are looking very hard on all ways to recover my money. Is it possible to recover ? Or is it completely gone ?

Only Kraken can. Try to insist with them, maybe threatening to call the authorities if they don't cooperate

Exodus is a non-custodial wallet so they won't be able to help. It is odd that Kraken do not support ETH on the base network. In their support page they state that it is supported https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/supported-assets-and-networks. Usually custodial wallets only support certain combinations and they won't help or charge a fee if you use an unsupported combination.
